# Function does not work after selecting a file to copy and place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out the real problem with my function below.
It copies the first time, but the second time it doesn't work. keeps only the last item copied

Script

```
function CopiarValorParaClipboard(id) {
if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(id));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
}

ExibirAlertaInferior('Link copiado!');
```

}

Html:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 130px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Nome)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px">
                    <p id="Link@(item.ArquivoId)" style="width: 700px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; margin: 0; padding: 0;">@item.LinkArquivo</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.DataValidade)
                </td>
                <td class="icones-arquivoslista" style="width: 10%;">
                    <a class="icone-lista" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="AbrirCampos('Arquivos', '@item.ArquivoId', '#divCampos', '#divLista')"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                    <a class="icone-lista" style="padding-left: 20px" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CopiarValorParaClipboard('Link@(item.ArquivoId)')"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Hey why are you using window.getSelection instead of window.getSelection()?